# Calculating the probability of the 'common birthday problem' differently yields a different result?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Everyone is calculating the birthday problem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)  by multiplying the probabilities of each person's birthday.  Like the following "first oe has $365/365$ the second has $364/365$..... and so on..." . And this is the complementary of the probability so you take $1$ minus it.

This is fine from a probability point of view. But once you go to combinatorics I get confused.

The thing that bothers me is that the formula you get in the end is similar to the combinatorial formula of choosing $k$ from $n$ if order matters divided by all possible selections of $k$.

My problem is that the formula should be calculated the same but when order **doesnt** matter.  That is, I want to choose $k$ days from a year of $365$ so I got ${365}\choose{k}$ all divided by $k+n-1  \choose  k$ which is the formula for choosing $k$ from $n$ with repetitions allowed and order doesn't matter.

I don't understand why it does not yield the same result. Even though this seems to me to be the correct way to solve it. Because I dont care about order, all what matters is that I choose k different days out of the year which is the complementary of the probability.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're asking here - when you say 'all divided by ${k+n-1\choose k}$', what does that mean exactly? why do you think that dividing by that is a 'correct' choice?

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't see your comment.   Take note that anguepa gave a good answer.  Tho not complete.   The reason I am saying to divide by it is very simple.   Because I want to divide by ALL  possibilities of selections with repetition and order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay maybe the best way to treat this is to look at an easy example. Let's say each year has only two days $\{1,2\}$ and there are two people. What is the probability that they share the same birthday?

Let's look at the probability that they have birthdays on different days. Following the logic of the birthday problem we have that the answer is $1/2$. 
Easily we note that this is correct, i.e. let $a$ and $b$ denote the birthday dates of person $A$ and $B$ respectively, we have there following equally likely possibilities for the tuple $(a,b)$: $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$ and $(2,2)$. And only two of them show different values, hence the answer is $2/4=1/2$.

Now using your approach we have that ${2}\choose{2}$ $=1$, namely the case $\{a,b\}=\{1,2\}$, and the number of possibilities with repetition when order doesn't matter is $3$, i.e. "$(1,1)$", "$(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$" and "$(2,2)$". So the answer would be $1/3$, which is clearly wrong.

I feel like the problem here is that trying to divide by outcomes with repetition where order doesn't matter means implicitly assigning the same probability to outcomes like "$(1,1)$" and "$(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$", which is mistaken.

So the best approach here seems to be to take into account order.

Comment: Very nice answer .  It turns out that when it comes to probability it isn't correct to use formulas that order doesn't matter.  Tho I saw ppl using it in poker so I believe they might be wrong?

Comment: not necessarily, but of course one must be careful with these things.

Answer (score 1):

The birthday probability can be written as:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-k/365)=\frac{364!/(365-n)!}{365^{n-1}}=\frac{\binom{365}{n}}{365^{n}/n!}.$$

To use binomial coefficients, you can reason as follows. If you have $n$ people, you need to choose $n$ distinct birthdays, which can be done in $\binom{365}{n}$ ways. The total number of ways of picking birthdays, when order in which you pick the people doesn't matter, is $365^{n}/n!$.

Comment: The total number of ways of picking birthdays, when order doesn't matter, is $365n/n!$, what does this mean exactly? Does it allow repetition? For example if we reduce the problem to two people having their birthday in one of two days $\{1,2\}$ the possibilities would be $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$ and $(2,2)$, so $3\neq 2^2/2!$.

Comment: Alex Thanx.  I also thought about that.  But is it correct that "The total number of ways of picking birthdays, when order doesn't matter, is 365n/n!." ???  I thought this is not correct and the correct way of calculating it is this (k+n-1  choose k)

Comment: Anguepa  is correct with his example.  Can someone please clear up the confusion?

Comment: @Anguepa: I think the confusion is stemming from whether order refers to the names of the people, or the dates of their birthdays. So I mean that 365^n/n! refers to the former. If it's the dates, then you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways we can pick $k$ days from $365$ is, of course, $365 \choose k$.

The number of ways that $N$ people can have their birthdays distributed over $k$ days, allowing for repetition, ignoring order, and requiring at least one on each day is $N-1 \choose k-1$.  This can be proven via induction on $k$.

The number of ways of ordering $N$ people, is, of course $N!$.

The number of ways $N$ people can have birthdays, counting different orders is $365^N$.

Thus, the probability that $N$ people have, between them, $k$ birthdays is:

$$p(k,N) = {{{365 \choose k} {N-1 \choose k-1} N! \over 365^N}} $$

For the case of $k=N$, this reduces to the known result.

Comment: What????? First of all we clearly not requesting for at least one in each day.  Secondly why did you divide by 365^n??? The whole point of the question is that I divide by (n+k-1 choos k)  because this is the formula when order doesn't matter.